# Interpretation of income rank variable

Tags: interpretation, normalization

I have an income rank variable which is calculated using the following formula:

Income rank = (j-1)/(n-1)

where j – 1 represents the number of people within the individuals' comparison group with lower income compared to this individual, and n represents the total number of individuals within this comparison group. This variable is thus normalized between 0 and 1, where 1 represents the "best" economic position compared to others, and 0 represents the worst.

My question regards to the interpretation of this variable's coefficient in a regression analysis. I understand that the coefficient represents the change in y for any one-unit increase in income rank, but it is less clear to me what is the "one unit" - is it any value of this variable? is it some other fixed value? or is it moving from 0 to 1?

I ask because I saw in some papers interpretations that say that one-unit increase in this variable means a shift from the bottom to the top (i.e., from 0 to 1). If this is the case, I'd really like to know why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one shift up in this variable means a shift from one position up in the whole ranking expressed as a percentage since it is bound between 0 and 1. So one shift up means one percent less people in front of your focal individual, and one percent more behind.